# How to read line by line and override a line in the same file

Tags: c++

I read line by line of a textfile and if a line meets some requirements I want to override the line and save it at the same position in the same file.

Here is what I have (simplified):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    fstream file;
    string line;
    file.open("Test.txt");

    while (getline(file, line))
    {
      if (line.size() > 7) file << line.append(" <- long line");
    }
}
```

Comment: Files work by byte position, not line. If you want to change the length of a line, I would suggest changing your code to output in a different file. Then perhaps you can replace the original with the new file.

Comment: You need to learn about and understand files.  In their simplest form, they are a sequence of bytes.  A text file is thus a sequence of bytes interpreted as characters.  If the bytes make sense as characters, then the file is readable, else it looks to the human as garbage.  Lines are simply a variable sequence of characters ending with a newline or carriage-return newline combination.  If you want to replace a line then without affecting its position or other lines' positions, you must replace it with the same number of characters (including newline).

Comment: @Les why does the new line have to have the same number of characters? What if my new line has one character more, then the old?

Comment: BTW, fstream is a stream, and stream implies reading continuously from, not random access to the file, which is what you will need to replace any bytes or sequence of bytes.  Consider using a lower level io, one with the ability to open read/write.

Comment: If your new line has more characters than the one it replaces, it overwrites the beginning of the next line.  Even though lines may vary in length, once they are written to the file, they each have their own fixed length.

Comment: +1 @owacoder for the suggestion to write to a new file.  A newbie to C and working with files should first learn how to read one and write another before trying to do in-place-overwrites.  You can always remove the original and rename the new.

Comment: @Les ah okay I understand!
What about creating a string array and saving each line in there. Now you can add even more characters to lines and do what ever you want. At the end you print line by line from the string array to a file. 
?

Comment: @Joey, yes, you can read all lines storing each in a string array or something more dynamic like a vector of string.  Then you have all the methods of "string" to work with, and then you can write the stings back to the file (first truncate the file).  But again, often the best practice is to write to a temporary file, then blow away the original if there were no errors, replacing with the temporary.

Comment: @Les Okay, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read your file into memory and then write it out after changing any of the lines.  The following example reads it into a vector, then writes it back out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    string line;
    file.open("Test.txt", fstream::in);
    if (file.fail()) exit(-1);

    vector<string> vec;
    while (getline(file, line, '\n'))
    {
        string ln = line;
        vec.push_back(ln);
    }
    file.close();

    // manipulate your lines here

    file.open("Test.txt", fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
    for (vector<string>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
    {
        file.write(it->c_str(), it->length());
        file.write("\n", 1);
    }
    file.close();
}
```

But note, when you change a line, the position of lines that follow will change unless the line you are changing is the same size as the original.  Also note, this is a simple ANSI file example, but UNICODE and UTF-8 are also common text file formats.  This should at least get you started.